# How to use UDP port listening with my Flask web server, problem with threads

Tags: multithreading, sockets, flask, multiprocessing, flask-socketio

Here the problem. I have my simple Flask web server with socketio module connected. On the client side there is some container which uses js script to get messages from server and show it in browser in realtime. On server side I need to listen other UDP port to recieve the messages and transmit recieved messages to client`s browser.When I've used BackgroundScheduler() to generate periodical test messages it worked fine. Now I'm adding my port listener to my web server executed in another thread and it doesn't transmit messages. It listens UDP port, it can print recieved messages to python console, it also gives the html page as before, but the messages is not returned from the thread to Flask app. I've tried to use multiprocessing, added my port listener to a separate process, but it didn't worked.It doesn't call any exceptions, it just do nothing. How can I find solution of my problem?

```
class TestUdp(BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        data = self.request[0].strip()
        socket = self.request[1]
        if data:
            socketio.send(data.decode('utf-8')
        socket.sendto(data.upper(), self.client_address)


def run():
    HOST, PORT = "127.0.0.1", 7030
    with UDPServer((HOST, PORT), TestUdp) as server:
        server.serve_forever()
```

This function inserted to my Flask route:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():

    t1=Thread(target=run,daemon=True)

    return render_template('main.html')
```

js code from html:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        socket.send('I\'m connected!');
    });
    socket.on('message', data => {
        console.log(`${data}`)
    });
    socket.on('message', data => {
        const p = document.createElement('li');
//        const br = document.createElement('br');
        p.innerHTML ="<li>"+ data + "</li>" ;
//        document.querySelector('#message').append(p);
         var resultList = document.getElementById('resultList');
            resultList.append(p);
    });
})
```

Comment: Your flask server starts a new thread each time a client retrieves `/index`. Each of those threads tries to start a server at the same address. This may not be the cause of your problem, but it is probably not a correct setup.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Look at the socketio.send call in the handle method, it's missing a closing parenthesis. Also, are you using eventlet or gevent in your Socket.IO server? If you are, then you can't emit from a separate thread, threads are essentially incompatible with eventlet/gevent, you may be able to do it using a greenlet, or with monkey patching.